# Drawing Path JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a `Path` in JavaFX that has a set of `MoveTo`. I am adding the `Path` to a `Pane`. Since a `Path` is a `Node`, it should draw itself automatically, right? The `Pane` says it has the `Path` as a child, but it is not drawing itself. What am I missing here?

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Path` consists of the collection of [PathElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/PathElement.html)s. `MoveTo` is one of them but it moves the starting point of current path, you can make an analogy with mouse cursor like on drawing applications. First you move the mouse cursor to desired place and start drawing by mouse clicking or dragging. To start drawing with `Path`, use other path elements, for instance `LineTo`.

```
Path path = new Path();

// First move to starting point
MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
moveTo.setX(100.0f);
moveTo.setY(50.0f);

// Then start drawing a line
LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
lineTo.setX(75.0f);
lineTo.setY(255.0f);

path.getElements().add(moveTo);
path.getElements().add(lineTo);
```

For some interesting demo see [Draw a semi ring - JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719005/draw-a-semi-ring-javafx).